# WCF SoapUI WsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, soapui, wshttpbinding

I am hoping someone can help me with this. I am trying to use SoapUI to invoke a WCF service with WsHttpBinding.  The service requires that I pass the client certificate.  How can I pass this in Soap UI?  I can easily create a client and invoke the service but I would like to be able to do this in SoapUI.

Is this possible and if yes, it would be greatly appreciated to get the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check for few things.

1) Set negotiateServiceCredential="false"

```
<wsHttpBinding>
   <binding name="wsHttpSecure">
      <security mode="Message">
         <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false"    
                  establishSecurityContext="false" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

2) Also make sure in SOAP UI you check mark "Add default WSA To"

Check this link
  http://ddkonline.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/wcf-45-host-unreachable-when-calling.html

3) For passing client certificate check following link

http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html

I hope that helps.